# How to read pointer variable value in Turbo Pascal?

Tags: turbo-pascal

I have the following code in Object Oriented Turbo Pascal (an example). And also, some questions for you guys, who have the knowledge of Turbo Pascal - because I can't find any answers.

```
type PMyNumber =^TMyNumber;
     TMyNumber = object(TObject)
                 Number1:real;
                 Number2:real;
                 constructor Init(x,y:real);
                end;
```

Question #1

I see code like `new(PMyNumber,Init(-4,0))` - is it some type of an object constructor ?

---

Question #2

```
someVariable := PMyNumber(MyColl[myIndex]^.At(j))^.Number1
```

I try to view the value of the `MyColl[myIndex]^.At(j)`. To do so, I open the `Evaluate/modyfy` window, but after click on `Evaluate` button, the I get the following error - what's wrong ?

[image]

moreover (I don't think the `)` char is needed here:

[image]

---

Question #3

how to read the pointer variable value ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, `Init()` is the name of the constructor.
2. You cannot evaluate a function call (`At()` is a member function of TMyNumber inherited from TObject).
3. If mean how to interpret the Pascal pointer notation: a leading '$' means hexadecimal value. The first value ($888F) is the segment and the second value ($8) is the offset within the segment. (Assuming you understanding the concept segments in a 16-environment.) If you mean how to read the value of a pointer at runtime: Use `seg()` to get the segment and `ofs()` to get the offset, like `seg(MyColl[myindex])` and `ofs(MyColl[myindex])`.